# How to stop Jenkins from using TEST SITE certificate when attempting to access through HTTPS

Tags: macos, jenkins, https

I am having a difficult time attempting to get HTTPS working with our Jenkins box (Mac Pro 2014 / OSX Mavericks / Jenkins Mac Installer).

After following the instructions at the bottom of [Jenkins-CI](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins):

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist

sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/org.jenkins-ci httpsPort 8443
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/org.jenkins-ci httpsKeyStore /path/to/your/keystore/file
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/org.jenkins-ci httpsKeyStorePassword <keystore password>

sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
```

My certificate is still invalid when accessing `https://myjenkins.com:8443`. After reviewing the certificate, it looks as though the a 'TEST SITE' certificate is still being used.

[image]

I have attempted the following:

- Passing .JKS and .P12 keystore types.
- Using a combined .CRT and .KEY and passing the following instead of httpsKeyStore and httpsKeyStorePassword:

  ```
  sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/org.jenkins-ci httpsCertificate /path/to/certificate
  sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/org.jenkins-ci httpsPrivateKey /path/to/key
  ```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It may sound silly, but clear out your browser cache and restart it. I've had SSL certs hang on unknowingly while beating my head against the wall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into this same issue and the problem is that the jenkins-runner.sh script does not pass the httpsPrivateKey and httpsCertificate variables from the plist file to the commandline used to launch Jenkins.  I added these two lines to jenkins-runner.sh to fix it.

```
add_to_args httpsPrivateKey
add_to_args httpsCertificate
```

The file is in the /Library/Application Support/jenkins directory on my machine.  You should be able to find the location on your machine by looking at the /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist file.